# Why is 5[a] valid and does not generate an error of invalid identifier?

Tags: c, arrays, identifier

In [With arrays, why is it the case that a[5] == 5[a]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381542/with-c-arrays-why-is-it-the-case-that-a5-5a) it is explained that the `[]` operator in `a[5]` is defined as `*(a + 5)` and because `+` is commutative, `5[a]` means `*(5 + a)` and so the two expressions refer to the same memory location. Fine.

However, C also defines in 6.4.2.1 that an identifier cannot start with a digit. In `5[a]` the array identifier is `5` which is not a valid identifier. Why does `5[a]` not generate an error about an invalid identifier?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`5` is not an identifier, it is an integer literal.

The C standard literally state that `5[a]` is just syntactic sugar that *must* be equivalent with `*(5 + a)`. There is no requirement in C that the first operand of the + operator is an identifier, so the code works just fine.

6.5.6, emphasis mine:

> For addition, either both operands shall have arithmetic type, or **one
>   operand shall be a pointer to a complete object type and the other
>   shall have integer type**.

Comment: FYI: The C standard uses the term _integer constant_ (which clarifies there are no (symbolic) constants as in other languages).